# Application design to support both MSSQL and MySQL as backend

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC application that currently supports MSSQL. The communication with database is through an adapter of sorts where I generate the MSSQL queries.

I would like this application to also support MySQL database. Whether to use MySQL or MSSQL must be configurable. What would be the best design strategy to get this done?

Comment: Complete separation of the application logic from the data access layer. This is the only strategy that works.

Comment: @Ritik Kumar I agree with Shadow. Separate the Layer so you just need to handle the difference in the data-layer. Further it may help you to just use SQL-Standard so that your statements work on both systems.

Comment: @Shadow, The application logic is already well separated from the data access layer. I ll add a high level application design diagram to make it clear.